# Как запустить pyrogram асинхронно с pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyrogram

Надо запустить pyrogram бота асинхронно с pyqt, чтобы через интерфейс pyqt можно было взаимодействовать с ботом.
При попытке запустить через QThread бот ругается, что запущен не в основном потоке, но способов решения этой проблемы я не нашёл.
Есть варианты как запустить бота в основном потоке?